# bash single quote escaping is driving me mad

Tags: bash

I'm trying to use gdalsrsinfo to get the proj4 string from a .shp and then pass it to ogr2ogr for use in a batch reprojection loop. It's close to working, but the single quotes are getting passed to the ogr2ogr command and I can't figure out how to strip them off:

My script:

```
        #!/bin/bash
for f in *.shp; do 
    projsrs=$(gdalsrsinfo -o proj4 $f)
    ogr2ogr -f "ESRI Shapefile" -s_srs "$projsrs" -t_srs EPSG:3857 ${f%}3857.shp $f
done
```

running the `gdalsrsinfo` command by itself returns:

```
username:shpfrm username$ gdalsrsinfo -o proj4 filename.shp
'+proj=utm +zone=11 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs '
```

When I use `bash -x` to test the output, I see that `''\'` is at the beginning of the string and `\'''` is on the end.

```
+ for f in '*.shp'
++ gdalsrsinfo -o proj4 filename.shp
+ projsrs=''\''+proj=utm +zone=11 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs '\'''
+ ogr2ogr -f 'ESRI Shapefile' -s_srs ''\''+proj=utm +zone=11 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs '\''' -t_srs EPSG:3857 filename.shp3857.shp PC_Sec05_Frm64.shp
Failed to process SRS definition: '+proj=utm +zone=11 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs '
```

what I need is:

```
ogr2ogr -f 'ESRI Shapefile' -s_srs '+proj=utm +zone=11 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs ' -t_srs EPSG:3857 filename.shp3857.shp filename.shp
```

Comment: This means that `gdalsrsinfo -o proj4 filename.shp` outputs literal single quotes. No characters are being added by anything. For why strings with single quotes aren't being interpreted as bash code, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12136948/why-does-shell-ignore-quotes-in-arguments-passed-to-it-through-variables).

Comment: It's not clear what exactly you're trying to do. For example, what's wrong with `projsrs=$(gdalsrsinfo -o proj4 $f); ogr2ogr -f "ESRI Shapefile" -s_srs "$projsrs" -t_srs EPSG:3857 ${f%}3857.shp $f`?

Comment: that was getting really confusing. updated and simplified for clarity. still getting the extra escaped single quotes when i put the variable in double quotes.

Comment: Without seeing the raw output from `gdalsrsinfo` there's not much to say. This looks like it should be fine, though you should quote wherever you're using `$f` and I'm not sure what you're doing with `${f%}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't shown the output from the command, but if it does have stray quotes that you don't want, you could just remove them. Reference: http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe#search_and_replace

```
#!/bin/bash
for f in *.shp; do 
    projsrs=$(gdalsrsinfo -o proj4 "$f")
    ogr2ogr -f "ESRI Shapefile" -s_srs "${projsrs//\'/}" -t_srs "EPSG:3857" "${f}3857.shp" "$f"
done
```

Also, you should always quote filenames, as they can contain spaces.

Comment: This worked perfectly. I need to learn a lot more about that replacement you did--thanks for the link to the resource.